# How to store an array of date ranges in Postgres?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, date, sql-insert

I am trying to build a schedule, I generate an array of objects on the client containing date ranges

```
[ 
    {start: "2020-07-06 0:0", end: "2020-07-10 23:59"}, 
    {start: "2020-07-13 0:0", end: "2020-07-17 23:59"} 
]
```

I have a column of type `daterange[]` what is the proper way to format this data to insert it into my table?

This is what I have so far:

```
INSERT INTO schedules(owner, name, dates) VALUES (
    1, 
    'work', 
    '{
         {[2020-07-06 0:0,2020-07-10 23:59]},
         {[2020-07-13 0:0,2020-07-17 23:59]}
    }'
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want:

```
insert into schedules(owner, name, dates) values (
    1, 
    'work', 
    array[ 
        '[2020-07-06, 2020-07-11)'::daterange, 
        '[2020-07-13, 2020-07-18)'::daterange 
    ]
);
```

Rationale:

- you are using `daterange`s, so you cannot have time portions (for this, you would need `tsrange` instead); as your code stands, it seems like you want an inclusive lower bound and an exclusive upper bound (hence `[` at the left side, and `)` at the right side)
- explicit casting is needed so Postgres can recognize the that array elements have the proper datatype (otherwise, they look like `text`)
- then, you can surround the list of ranges with the `array[]` constructor

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5cc95b6ce455586c3aa8ca4adc0a6367)**:

```
owner | name | dates                                                
----: | :--- | :----------------------------------------------------
    1 | work | {"[2020-07-06,2020-07-11)","[2020-07-13,2020-07-18)"}
```

Comment: Awesome! tsrange is what I needed. Do you mind explaining what an inclusive lower bound and exclusive upper bound is?

Comment: @Ayn: you can have a look at [the relevant part of the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INCLUSIVITY). Actually, I think that `daterange` is closer to what you want here (based on the fact that the time portions of your upper bould are `23:59`)...

Comment: Thanks! I see what you mean in this particular example but some dates might not include the whole day and might include partial hours.

I think I am understanding things better now.